# htaccess IP to HTTPS redirection on a domain with a special rewrite mod exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, htdocs

I want to redirect the IP to a domain but the issue that there is an already Rewritecond & RewriteRule exists in the .htaccess and couldn't merge them together :

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

To redirect IP to domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^50\.50\.60\.60
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This how it's working now :

From

> http://example.com/

to

> https://www.example.com/en/

The Whole issue is the with

> /en/

It connects to Language.php on every URL and adds /en/

```
$config['default_language'] = 'en';
```

No idea how it's possible to merge this together i have tried lot of methods but noone worked.

This File is MY_Lang.php that selects the language from Language.php and adds it to the URL

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        global $CFG;
        global $URI;
        require_once APPPATH . "config/language.php";
        $this->supported_languages = array_key_exists('supported_languages', $config) && !empty($config['supported_languages']) ? $config['supported_languages'] : $this->supported_languages;
        $this->current_language = array_key_exists('default_language', $config) && !empty($config['default_language']) ? $config['default_language'] : $this->current_language;
        $this->detect_language = array_key_exists('detect_language', $config) ? $config['detect_language'] : $this->detect_language;
        $this->default_uri = array_key_exists('default_uri', $config) ? $config['default_uri'] : $this->default_uri;
        $this->special_uris = array_key_exists('special_uris', $config) ? $config['special_uris'] : $this->special_uris;
        $this->uri = $URI->uri_string();
        $uri_segment = $this->get_uri_lang($this->uri);
        $this->lang_code = $uri_segment['lang'];
        $url_ok = FALSE;
        if((!empty($this->lang_code)) && (array_key_exists($this->lang_code, $this->supported_languages)))
        {
            $language = $this->supported_languages[$this->lang_code]['folder'];
            $CFG->set_item('language', $language);
            $this->current_language = $this->lang_code;
            $url_ok = TRUE;
        }
        if((!$url_ok) && (!$this->is_special($uri_segment['parts'][0]))) // special URI -> no redirect
        {
            // set default language
            $this->current_language = $this->default_lang();
            $CFG->set_item('language', $this->supported_languages[$this->current_language]['folder']);
            $uri = (!empty($this->uri)) ? $this->uri : $this->default_uri;
            $uri = ($uri[0] != '/') ? '/' . $uri : $uri;
            $new_url = $CFG->config['base_url'] . $this->default_lang() . $uri;
            header("Location: " . $new_url, TRUE, 302);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always place such external redirection rules _above_ (so higher up in the file) other internal rewriting rules. And you need to take care not to redirect https requests to the actual domain (use an additional condition for that). Then nothing speaks against combining both.

Comment: I also tried that but it couldn't work, i have tried every possible way that i know to merge them.

Comment: And "it doesn't work" means _what_ exactly? Please add your attempt to the question and explain in detail what exactly happens and why you consider that wrong.

Comment: Also please elaborate where that redirection to `/en/` comes from. It is not part of the rules you posted. So you have additional rules in place you did not mention here.

Comment: It's getting the Language from Language.php and adds it to the Link.

Comment: "htaccess IP to HTTPS redirection" - I'm not sure what this has to do with the rest of your question? You state the `.htaccess` rule that does this, but under your "This how it's working now" you've given an example of something else - no mention of IP address redirection? "couldn't merge them together" - they are not meant to be "merged together". They do two entirely different things and should remain as two entirely separate rules, but as noted by arkascha in the first comment, the "redirect" must go first.

Comment: You also can't combine redirects if one is performed by Apache in `.htaccess` and the other is performed by PHP. By the sounds of it, the language redirect is "complex" and needs to be performed by PHP, so why not do both in PHP?

Comment: I have already put them both together and they simply doesn't work, no matter what : 
I put them together than noone works.